# Remove Duplicates from a table headers in Excel in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to remove multiple duplicates in Excel 2016 VBA from a imported XML file.

It works with a array:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("%tableName%").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(8, 10, 12, 26, 40), Header:=xlYes
```

But I the problem is that I don't always know what column my data I want to remove duplicates from is. this week it could be 8, 10, 12, 26, 40 next week it could be 9, 10, 15, 26, 40.

It is always the same table header names:

```
'8 = Range("%tableName%[udsendelses_dato]")
'10 = Range("%tableName%[start_tid]")
'12 = Range("%tableName%[udsendelses_titel]")
'26 = Range("%tableName%[Titel]")
'40 = Range("%tableName%[Varighed]")
```

Comment: Do you want to remove whole column if it have same header as some other column which already is in your document? Is that what are you asking?

Comment: Might want  to edit your question so that you ask a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be simpler but since it is a Table (a `ListObject` in Excel VBA), this should do:

```
With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    .Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array( _
        .ListColumns("udsendelses_dato").index, _
        .ListColumns("start_tid").index, _
        .ListColumns("udsendelses_titel").index, _
        .ListColumns("Titel").index, _
        .ListColumns("Varighed").index), _
        Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: Nice. Good use of column index property. :)