# VBA Macro that removes duplicates based on column names

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to Excel VBA I made this macro to remove duplicates based on column name "container". Now there are 2 columns in excel with the name "Container".

```
  Sub Remove_DupContainerPOL()
    
    'Removes Duplicate Containers
    
    Dim whs As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, colNumber As Long
    Dim colh As String
    
    colh = "Container"
    lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set whs = Worksheets("POL")
    colNumber = Application.Match(colh, whs.Range("A1:AAA1"), 0)
    
         With whs.Range("A1:AAA" & lRow)
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=colNumber, Header:=xlYes
         End With
    
    End Sub
```

[Original Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0pLU.png)

This is how the columns look like in the excel file. Now when I execute the macro it misbehaves somehow not sure the entire data in preceding rows get shuffled and generates the wrong output.
Is there any way that macro reads the 3 columns i.e. "Container" and only based on that removes duplicates?

Further, I am adding an explanation in detail.
Tab named Ocean which has 2 columns named Container! I coded in a way that the data in this ocean creates 2 new tabs named POL and POD and in that POL and POD tab I want to remove the duplicates based on the column named “Container” which is creating the wrong output.
Main Ocean tab where duplicate data.

POL Tab where Macro shuffled the data and gave wrong output

My complete macro codes below:

```
Sub Split_Ocean()

'------------------------------Filter on column Mode and split all Ocean moves into newsheet--------------------------

    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    ' If the code is in the ActiveWorkbook you should use ThisWorkbook instead.
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        
    ' Delete Target Worksheet.
    Dim FSht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FSht = wb.Worksheets("Ocean")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        FSht.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet.
    Set FSht = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    FSht.Name = "Ocean"
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim Tsht As Worksheet
    Set Tsht = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    With Tsht
        If Tsht.AutoFilterMode Then
            Tsht.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
        ' 14 is column N
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Ocean"
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy FSht.Range("A1")
    End With

'-------------------------------------------------Endforabovecode---------------------
'Wait for 3 sec

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
'Create POL

Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Destination As Worksheet

'Checking whether "POL" sheet already exists in the workbook
For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Source.Name = "POL" Then
        MsgBox "POL sheet already exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ocean").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = "POL"

'Autofit all contents in POL

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit


'Create POD & check whether "POD" sheet already exists in the workbook

For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Source.Name = "POD" Then
        MsgBox "POD sheet already exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ocean").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = "POD"

'Autofit all contents in POD

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POD").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub

Sub Remove_DupContainerPOL()

'Removes Duplicate Containers

Dim whs As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, colNumber As Long
Dim colh As String

colh = "Container"
lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set whs = Worksheets("POL")
colNumber = Application.Match(colh, whs.Range("A1:E1"), 0)

     With whs.Range("A1:E1" & lRow)
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=colNumber, Header:=xlYes
     End With

End Sub

Sub Remove_DupContainerPOD()

'Removes Duplicate Containers

Dim whs As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, colNumber As Long
Dim colh As String

colh = "Container"
lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set whs = Worksheets("POD")
colNumber = Application.Match(colh, whs.Range("A1:E1"), 0)

     With whs.Range("A1:E1" & lRow)
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=colNumber, Header:=xlYes
     End With

End Sub
```

[Main Ocean tab where duplicate data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHOvW.png)

[POL Tab where Macro shuffled the data and gave wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0egmo.png)

Comment: `With whs.Range("A1:E1" & lRow)   .RemoveDuplicates` should be `With whs.Range("A1:N" & lRow)` 
to cover all the columns (assuming N is last column). Or maybe just use `With whs.UsedRange`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478225/remove-duplicates-from-a-table-headers-in-excel-in-vba?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`With whs.Range("A1:E1" & lRow)   .RemoveDuplicates` should be With `whs.Range("A1:N" & lRow)` to cover all the columns (assuming N is last column). Or maybe just use `With whs.UsedRange`.